# OpenCV-Python: cv2.imshow doesn't stop working

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I wrote simple program just to try to open photo using cv2.imshow():

```
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('images/8d47d369_2022-10-06_18-18-30_0.jpg')
print(img)
if img is None:
    raise RuntimeError('Could not read image')

cv2.imshow('Original image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But I it didn't work. The window with photo doesn't open, and script doesn't stop too. I need to terminate it, or it just runs without any result and without errors.

I tried different things:

1. I remover `cv2.waitKey(0)`, resut the same. Also, I tried to `print(cv2.imread())`, and it showed numpy ndarray as expected. So, this command work normally.
2. I created new venv and install opencv-python there, doesn't work either.
3. I tried to start this script in PyCharm, VSCode and Jupyter Notebook. The same problem in PyCharm and VSCode, in Jupyter Notebook kernel just died.
4. I used opencv before, and have another jupyter notebooks with it. All of them now doesn't work either.

I think that root of this problem in installation of opencv-python, maybe there are problems with packages, which important for OpenCV work, but I didn't find information about it. Hope that someone will help me with this problem!
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Are you sure the build of OpenCV you installed is built with some HIghGUI backend? From what I've seen the default Linux flavours often aren't. | Did you try running this with a regular command line Python interpreter, rather than in Jupyter? I assume this Jupyter instance isn't running on some headless remote machine (HighGUI module is not designed to be used in such scemarios -- you need to run it locally).

Comment: Try `cv2.waitKey(-1)`. And add a last line `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`. See [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html)!